# Laravel ORM get all books from a list of authors

Tags: php, sql, orm, laravel

I have a model for book and one for author.
The book model has a belongsTo author relationship, and author hasMany books.

I have a `sql` query that gives me some authors and now i want all those authors books together in one list.

I thought I could write:

```
$authors->books
```

But this gives me the error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$books
```

I know I can call `$author->books` if it is a single author I have, but what if I like in this case a collection of authors, how can I get all their books together?

Comment: Not sure, but can't you iterate through this collection to apply `->books` on each element?

Comment: @RoyalBg Yes, but how do I save those ->books to an array, so I get an array with all books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're retrieving multiple Authors, Laravel returns it as a Collection. You cannot query on a collection, which means you have to run through it with a foreach for example.

**By iterating through the collection**

```
$allBooks = array();

foreach ($authors as $author){
    $authorBooks = $author->books->get()->toArray();
    $allBooks = array_merge($allBooks, $authorBooks);
}
```

I do recommend using scopes though.

**An other solution might be working with scopes:**

Create an array with your author id's. You can use ->lists('id') for this when using an object. (In this example, I take all authors, but you can restrict with ->where or a scope.)

```
$authorids= Author::all()->lists('id');
```

Create a scopeAuthorIds in your Book model, something like this:

```
public function scopeAuthorIds($query, $ids)
{
return $query->whereIn('authorId', $ids);
}
```

You should be able to filter your books on the author id's now, by doing

```
$allBooks = Book::AuthorIds($authorids)->get();
```

Comment: @Skullbox Updated my post to answer your question about adding the books to an array. I do recommend using scopes though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `with('books')` [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading):

```
$authors = Author::with('books')->get();
```

Make sure you have following function in `Author` model:

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Book');
}
```

Using of `::with('Book')` will solves (less queries) the `n+` query (known as eager loading) problem. Next, you can use a loop like this:

```
foreach($authors as $author) {
    // Assumed you have a name property in authors table
    echo $author->name; // in blade use {{ $author->name }} to echo
    foreach($author->books as $book) {
        // Assumed you have a title property in books table
        echo $book->title; // in blade use {{ $book->title }} to echo
    }
}
```

Without the loop you may get any model from a collection using this:

```
// Assumed 1 is the id here in both cases
$author->find(1)->books->find(1)->title;
```

Or you may use something like this:

```
$author->first()->books->first()->title;
$author->first()->books->find(2)->title;
```

You may use `get(index)` to get an item from the colection using the index of that item like this:

```
// First author model and first book model
$author->get(0)->books->get(0)->title;
```

Just remember, `$author` is a collection and `$author->books` is also a collection. You may [like this](http://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object).